# Vuetify <v-autocomplete> v-model object instead of array doesn't add correctly

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm doing a hobby project with Vuetify input fields in rows. One of the fields is a v-autocomplete field with 'multiple' prop set. I need to bind this v-autocomplete using v-model to an Object. 
How do I do this?

### I've tried:

- Overriding the template using v-slot.
- Adding item-value and item-text. This made it display correctly. Nice! Updating doesn't work though. Somehow v-model makes it an array of strings instead of saving as objects. Like so:

Before adding extra items from the list:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbx8h.png

After adding extra items from the list:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEKDv.png

The v-model list is no longer filled with objects that have their "action" and "amount" props. Instead it makes it a list of Strings

### Code:

Code in template:

```
<v-layout wrap v-for="(row, index) in rows" :id="index+1 + 'buildorderRow'" v-bind:key="index">
   <v-autocomplete
      v-model="row.actions"                                          
      :items="protoss"
      chips                                            
      item-value="action"
      item-text="action"
      multiple
   >
</v-layout>
```

Array binded to v-model:

```
                    actions: [
                        {
                            action: 'Gateway',
                            amount: 5
                        },
                        {
                            action: 'Pylon',
                            amount: 1
                        },
                    ],
```

### Expectation

I expected it to add any selection to the array while maintaining the model structure. Just like it does for reading the array. For instance if I add an action of "Probe" it should create it like shown below. Amount could also be Null/undefined or even completely left out. The important thing is that it pushes the object with the action prop.

{ 
action: 'Probe',
amount: 1
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `return-object` prop on the `autocomplete` to get the value as an object. `return-object` changes the selection behavior to return the object directly rather than the value specified with item-value.

```
<v-layout wrap v-for=“(row, index) in rows” :id=“index+1 + ‘buildorderRow’” v-bind:key=“index”>
   <v-autocomplete
      v-model=“row.actions”
      :items=“protoss”
      chips
      item-value=“action”
      item-text=“action”
      multiple
      return-object
   >
</v-layout>
```